# CSS : vertically centered more than one text

Tags: html, css

I have a div which have the text in the center of it.
when I write second text then instead of having next line in the center it displays on the same line.

```css
.selection_of_speakers_no_div {
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: flex;
 height: 115px;
 text-align: center;
  border:thin red solid;
}

.selection_of_speakers_no_div span {
 margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="selection_of_speakers_no_div">
  <span class="font_size_20">4</span>
  <span class="font_size_20">Speakers</span>
</div>
```

I want `speakers` text to be center and in the new line rather than on the same line.

Thank You.

Comment: try  ``flex-direction: column;``

Comment: thank you.. but there is too much space between 4 and speakers. can't it be less? just 5 or 6px;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `flex-direction: column` css property on parent element.

```
.selection_of_speakers_no_div {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

> Default value is `row` which makes child elements of flex container to appear in one row.

```css
.selection_of_speakers_no_div {
    padding: 35px 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    width: 115px;
    text-align: center;
    border:thin red solid;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.selection_of_speakers_no_div span {
 margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="selection_of_speakers_no_div">
  <span class="font_size_20">4</span>
  <span class="font_size_20">Speakers</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you.. but there is too much space between 4 and speakers. can't it be less? just 5 or 6px;

Comment: @Rishi this space is because of `height` that you have specified. You can remove or reduce this height.

Comment: actually i want the div to be square. that's why i have given height.

Comment: @Rishi use paddings instead of height

Comment: @Rishi I've updated my answer as well. You can use `width` or use `padding` on flex container.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `padding` in place of `height` for `.selection_of_speakers_no_div` and `flex-direction:column;`

```css
.selection_of_speakers_no_div {
    display: flex;
    padding: 55px;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    border:thin red solid;
}

.selection_of_speakers_no_div span {
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="selection_of_speakers_no_div">
  <span class="font_size_20">4</span>
  <span class="font_size_20">Speakers</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```css
.selection_of_speakers_no_div {
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: flex;
 min-height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
    border:thin red solid;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.selection_of_speakers_no_div span {
 margin: auto;
    outline:1px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="selection_of_speakers_no_div">
  <span class="font_size_20">4</span>
  <span class="font_size_20">Speakers</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.selection_of_speakers_no_div {
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 115px;
 text-align: center;
  border:thin red solid;
}

.selection_of_speakers_no_div span {
 margin: auto;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="selection_of_speakers_no_div">
      <span class="font_size_20">4</span>
                                                            <span class="font_size_20">Speakers</span>
                                                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<html>
<style>
.selection_of_speakers_no_div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    height: 115px;
    text-align: center;
  border:thin red solid;
}

.selection_of_speakers_no_div p {
    margin: auto;
}
</style>

<body>
   <div class="selection_of_speakers_no_div">
   <p class="font_size_20">
  <span>4</span>
  <span>Speakers</span>
  </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table-cell display style for div.

```css
.selection_of_speakers_no_div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 115px;
  height: 115px;
  text-align: center;
  border:thin red solid;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.selection_of_speakers_no_div span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="selection_of_speakers_no_div">
   <span class="font_size_20">4</span>
   <span class="font_size_20">Speakers</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flex direction property and use margin-top and margin-bottom between 2 span to select how much space you want between them.

```
.selection_of_speakers_no_div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
    height: 115px;
    text-align: center;
    border:thin red solid;
}

.selection_of_speakers_no_div span {
    margin: auto;
}
.selection_of_speakers_no_div span:first-child {
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}
.selection_of_speakers_no_div span:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
.selection_of_speakers_no_div span:last-child {
    margin-top: 1px;
}
```